# How to make a formula to change the number page in a link with excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make a formula to grab a link and change the page number progressively. for example to grab

https://www.walmart.com/search/?cat_id=0&facet=retailer%3AWalmart.com&grid=true&max_price=350&min_price=45&page=2&query=brown#searchProductResult

and throw the same link with page=2, page=3, and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Hyperlink()`:

Put this in say A1:

```
=Hyperlink("https://www.walmart.com/search/?cat_id=0&facet=retailer%3AWalmart.com&grid=true&max_price=350&min_price=45&page=" & row() & "&query=brown#searchProductResult","Link to page " & row())
```

And drag down.

Comment: Thank you That works but it's kinda manual I'll have to do it manually everytime. What if I want to make it more so like I only paste the link in lets say A1 and then from A3 it starts throwing all the links until lets say A13. I saw someone using LEFT() and RIGHT() but I don't know how to use those.

Comment: @AndresVilchez huh? Can you describe what you're looking for better, in your OP? You just want it to show through rows 3-13?

Comment: I already did it thank you. This is the formula I ended up using, N16 is the cell where I'm pasting the link and in A1 i have ="page="row() all the way down. =LEFT($N$16,FIND("page",$N$16)-1)&A1&right($N$16,len($N$16)-find("page",$N$16)-5)